# Django: Server Error (500) при выполнении функции после переноса на сервер

Tags: python-3.x, django, http-status-code-500

Локально всё работает прекрасно. После переноса на сервер, при нажатии на кнопку, функция не выполняется, а выходит ошибка Server Error (500). В чем может быть проблема и как исправить?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Fertig
from .forms import NewAnzeigenForm
from django.views.generic import DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView
import csv
from .filters import FertigFilter

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa


def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        with open('main/daten.csv') as File:
            reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')
            for row in reader:
                _, created = Fertig.objects.get_or_create(
                    name=row[0],
                    preis=row[1],
                    telefon=row[2],
                    beschreibung=row[3],
                    anzeigenummer=row[4],
                    standort=row[5],
                    online=row[6],
                    url=row[7],
                    bild=row[8]
                )
        return redirect('home')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('fertig', views.fertig, name='ready'),
    path('sortierung', views.sortierung, name='sortierung'),
    path('nachfrage', views.nachfrage, name='nachfrage'),
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('pdf/<pk>', views.anzeige_render_pdf_view, name='pdf-anzeige'),
    path('<int:pk>/details', views.FertigDetails.as_view(), name='details'),
    path('<int:pk>/update', views.FertigUpdateDetails.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete', views.FertigDeleteDetails.as_view(), name='delete')
]
```

html:

```
          </form>
              <form action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                   <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" type="submit">Daten importieren</button>
              </form>
```

Не работает только "upload" всё остальное в порядке.

Comment: возможно проблема с `with open('main/daten.csv') as File:` где лежит этот файл

Comment: Структура папок 1 в 1 была перенесена на сервер. Точно так же находится файл локально и всё работает...

Comment: ну вообще надо смотреть в логах на сервере из-за чего эта ошибка, без них остается только гадать

Comment: то что перенести точь в точь не значит что работает точь в точь. добавьте проверку что файл существует, если нет вызовите какое нить исключение или верните response чтобы это увидеть